# Setting source port for UDP packet with Scapy?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, scapy, spoofing

I am trying to spoof UDP packets for a school project, and I am using Scapy to do this. For my purposes, I need to be able to set the source port to a specific port. However, when I do this with Scapy, it doesn't seem to have the correct source port when received on the other end. For instance, if I listen with Wireshark, all of the packet contents are correct except for the source port. For reference, I am doing the following in Scapy (super simple):

```
a=IP()
set a.src and a.dst
b=UDP()
set b.dport and b.sport
payload="HELLO"
packet=a/b/payload
send(packet)
```

Any ideas as to why the port number is not coming out correctly when the packet is sent? Thanks!

Comment: What are the ports? What about a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't quite understand your code but this should do it:

```
myPack = IP() / UDP(sport=2000) / Raw('hello')
send(myPack)
```

Answer (score 1):

If somone is looking for how to use a random source port:

```py
from scapy.all import *
send(IP(src="1.3.3.7",dst="7.3.3.1")/UDP(sport=RandShort(),dport=13337)/Raw(load="hello"))
```